# How do I write an ongoing process in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array which the user puts in data from a website one at a time.  So the array keeps growing one at a time.  I want an ongoing process that will get the length of the array and if it's positive, prints and then splices the data, setTimeout(1000), and then keeps running.  So if the array has nothing, nothing is done, and whenever something gets put into the array something has to come out because the array is nonempty.

So how can I do something like this?

Sorry if the explanation is confusing...

I tried using while(true) but that just eats up memory so I'm not sure what else to do, (threads?). plz help. thx!

I'm not looking for an event listener.  I want to store data and release at an interval.  The event listener fills up the array, but I know how to do this.  I don't know how the loop will execute.

Comment: can't you attach an event handler to the control the user uses to provide the data?

Answer (score 0):

What about some event handlers? You don't want an ongoing processes if I understand your question correctly. You want to react on user input with an [event handler](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) .

Comment: it's not really the event listener that I'm interested in, I already know this, its the ongoing loop that I need to know how to write. because I'm not gonna echo responses but rather queue them up and then echo them every so often, so I need an ongoing process to do this

Answer (score 0):

Google uses a smart array push mechanism in its async Analytics script:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxx-yyy-zzz']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

This creates an empty queue array or uses the existing one if previous data hasn't been processed yet.

The main script, http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js contains a setTimeout loop that checks if the queue array contains data, and if so, processes it.

You could use a similar mechanism: simply check for new elements in the queue, process them, and clear the queue array when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `setTimeout` and a global array to achieve what you want, or you could do it the modern way.

Derek!! Meet the JavaScript [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)!  It is the finest of its age!  The cream of the crop!  A wonder of human achievement!  **It'll help you make a web app.**

Here's a [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aAJAX_and_Events).  And an outline of what you might want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[text]').change(function() {
     alert($(this).attr('value'));
   });
 });
```

Comment: Heck, if you really wanted, you could use the event listener to maintain a global array.  Just remember to use window["variable_name"] to get and set!

Comment: it's not really the event listener that I'm interested in, I already know this, its the ongoing loop that I need to know how to write.  because I'm not gonna echo responses but rather queue them up and then echo them every so often, so I need an ongoing process to do this

Answer (score 0):

or a recursive timer like this?

```
var z=[ 'Mazda',
        'Totyota',
        'Honda',
         'Suzuki'
      ];

var job = function()
{
   document.write(z.pop());
   setTimeout(job, 1000); // run every second
}();
```

Comment: looking into this but don't know how well this will work cuz my functions are en-capsulized in (function($){
    jQuery.fn.extend({ ... and also i'm using fadeOut and trying to timeout the splice of an array.... ugh

Comment: It could still work well in your plugin.  Keep in mind that if you are creating many 'threads' in your plugin, with each their own setTimeout, you're likely to have a slow app.  There must be a simpler way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok then, the `for` loop will help you
(your array is stored at `window.yourArray`):

```
for (var i=0; i < window.yourArray.length; i++){
    alert(window.yourArray[i]);
}
```

or simpler:

```
for (a in window.yourArray){
    alert(a);
}
```

These loops are much better than your `while(true)` loop because these have a finite lifespan (based on the number of elements in your array).  You should run one of these loops at regular intervals by using `setTimeout`.

Comment: sorry if my explanation is confusing, but i need a loop/recursion/process that can tell if it's already running so an event does not trigger it if it is already running, also the timeout is within the loop, like between each alert